# Why does Inno Setup fail while Extracting jar files?

Tags: java, inno-setup

For years I've used Inno Setup to build the installer for my rather large Windows app. Recently, Run began to fail while extracting the jar files. When this happens the dialog stays on the screen, completely unresponsive. The only way I and get rid  of it is to reboot Windows. I've discovered that if I then go to the app installation directory (in Program Files x86) and delete all the lib jar files the installer works.

In my Inno setup file I have only:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\CBDocs\ConcoursBuilderUser.ini";
```

This has always worked, but now that appears to not be sufficient.
I'm using Inno Setetup compiler 6.2.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the installer is installing something, the .iss cannot have only the `InstallDelete` => we need [mcve]. A log file would be useful too.

Comment: "In my Inno setup file I have only:" you only have 2 lines in your `.iss` file? It won't compile like that. As Martin says, we need a minimum reproducible example. (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Comment: I've tried to think of a "minimal" example but haven't succeeded. I was hoping someone else might have experienced this bizarre behavior and would share their experience. I'd be glad to share my iss file if someone wanted to look it over. If not, I'll struggle along.

Comment: A minimal example would be an `.iss` file that contains only the minimum amount of lines needed to reproduce the problem. Your `.iss` file cannot contain only those two lines because it would not compile that way. The goal is to provide an example of sufficient length so that someone else can see the _exact same failure_ on their machine. (Remember - again - we cannot see your screen!)

Comment: I can now see how unclear my original post was. I should have said "my InstallDelete section has only..." But really, how could "large Windows app" have a 2-line iss file?

Comment: I can now see how unclear my original post was. I should have said "my InstallDelete section has only..." But really, how could "large Windows app" have a 2-line iss file? Regarding MRE, I've plenty of experience writing such. My NetBeans projects include dozens of them, mostly rabbit holes. I admit it feels good when this approach actually works, but it's extremely  time consuming. I'm still hoping someone can suggest why Inno Setup might lead to the no-escape situation I report. Again, I'd be glad to share my entire iss file.

Comment: My recommendation is to build a `.iss` file that contains only the absolute minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. When I have done this, I have found that over 95% of the time I have discovered the cause of the problem on my own. This is why it's such a good recommendation: It helps _you_ debug the issue, and it also helps _others_ to _reproduce the problem with absolute minimal dependencies_.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks. I've had some success with the method over the several decades of coding. But in complex projects it can be very difficult. On the one in question, I've starred building the "absolute minimum" but soon give up. There are dozens of compressed jar files, e.g., glazed list which is the one that hangs up. But if I eliminate that one my code won't build, So I set about to create a little project with glazed lists. I don't know i'f you have worked with them, but there's no such thing as a "simple" example to start with.

Comment: Keep in mind that we only have the information you have provided. As such I just don't see how it is possible to answer your question with such limited information. Inno Setup works fine for me.

Comment: Well, I have offered to make my .iss file available but there were no takers. It seems that when one asks for help here theses days he/she is told to solve the problem and report back.  And to add insult to injury,  one gets negatives for asking the question! What kind of assistance is that? But rest assured, I will solve this problem and report the solution here.

Comment: When the request was to make the source file available, the assumption was that you would update your question with an absolute minimum, reproducible source file (i.e., put it directly in the question, not direct responders to a download that requires the responder to configure a complete environment on their own to try to reproduce the issue). Sorry if this wasn't clear. Also keep in mind that people answering questions here are volunteers, so my suggestion is to have appropriate expectations, particularly with complex issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved the problem. Western Digital used to offer a free disk management utility called TrueImage. At some point Acronis wrapped it into their applications so I switched to Acronis TrueImage, and signed up for their cloud backup services. It looks like when Inno Setup (IS) is trying to unzip a jar file Acronis TrueImage is doing something with the file too, thus blocking IS access. I hedge a little because only time will tell if I've got this right. I do know a couple things for sure. One, if I do the Delete of the previous version of my app outside of IS and then run my app installer it works flawlessly. Two, while the hung-up IS dialog was on the screen I went to Task Manager and killed Acronis TrueImage. **The IS dialog immediately finished and closed and my app was properly installed.**  I hope this helps some else.

BTW, signing up for Acronis is a till death do us part experience. Even though I've cancelled my account their software is on my computer and there is no way to remove it.

Comment: The is no longer any question in my mind. The problem was the interaction between Inno Setup and Acronis. If I were a developer of Inno Setup I'd be warning users of this problem.